# Where exactly is my second hdd?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Im completely new to ubuntu, so this might seem like a silly question, but I'm not sure where to locate my second hdd.

I installed Ubuntu onto a computer that had 2 already formatted hard drives in it.  I can locate the hdd and it's partition through the console (/dev/sdb1) so i know it's there, and I cannot mount it to a directory as it is already mounted somewhere I just don't know where ubuntu locates the drive by default.

There is an ejectable "new volume" under devices that I suspect may be my drive, but I am unable to write to it at all.  Any help here would be apreciated, thanks!

Comment: What partition is your drive?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, it is the primary and only partition on the drive and is ntfs as stated in the op it is called sdb1.

Comment: That's what I wanted. It's ntfs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Unity applications dash look for "Disks". It's a disk manager that you can use to apply a partition table (choose mbr/ms-dos), create a partition, and add a filesystem to your second hard drive. Then you should be able to mount the partition, and see it.

Comment: Oh wow, this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thank you!